# Testing Framework for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, automated-tests, mesosphere, minikube

I was working before in DCOS mesosphere . I used 'shakedown' framework for creating automation testing for workflow creation that will run as part of our CI/CD pipeline.  Now I want to do same kind of automation testing on K8s . Is there any framework that does the job of my interest?? 
Automation includes: deploying and installing the docker images, run basic functional and sanity test cases.